# JavaFX - ErrorStream into Label

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, redirect

I have a BufferedReader , reading the Input (Error) Stream from another Jarfile. I am running the other jarfile in another thread , and then I make a loop reading lines and then resetting the labels text. But it does not repaint. I have read that JavaFX is single threaded . But I dont know what to do. Here is the code:

```
Thread start = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
        try{
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaw -Xmx2048M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true --nojline");
            data.setInputStream(proc.getErrorStream());
            data.setOutputStream(proc.getOutputStream());
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader readr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data.getInputStream()));
        data.setServerStarted(true);
        String line;
        while(data.serverStarted()){
            try {
                if((line = readr.readLine()) != null){
                    data.cons.setText(data.cons.getText() + line + "\n");//cons is the label
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try {
                    readr.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }}};
        start.start();
```

But if I try to run this one at the same thread , the program will not be responding. I am doing some label rewriting BUT , it is in the same thread, Then , immediately after rewriting . I get a line from the jar's inputstream. This is the code:

```
public void sendCommand(String command){
    if(data.serverStarted()){
    if (!(command.equalsIgnoreCase(""))){
    if(!(command.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))){
        try {
            data.cons.setText(data.cons.getText() + ">" + command + "\n");
            data.bw.write(command);
            data.bw.newLine();
            data.bw.flush();
            data.tl.setText("Type your command here...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        data.cons.setText(data.cons.getText() + "This command is not allowed!" + "\n");
    }
    }else{
        data.cons.setText(data.cons.getText() + "Please make sure that you have entered a command" + "\n");
    }
    }else{
        data.cons.setText(data.cons.getText() + "Please start your server first!" + "\n");
    }
}
```

If I try to send a command , no matter what stage do I do it , if I mess with cons.setText(); , It will give me something like this:
      http://prntscr.com/27w6yv , while the standard MS-DOS startup would be like this:
      http://prntscr.com/27w79v . It is not about the amount of ram I allocate or the CPU power. I have 8GBs of ram and I allocate both 2 at the JavaFX program and at the server.(It is a minecraft server anyway). The CPU is i5-3570K. This is weird because this program is a remake of my previous one , built with JFrame. There everything works smoothly! Please help me!
(The line that appears at the GUI , is the first one , nevermind what it is. If I add another setText() before the loop , only it will appear.)

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-6
```

---------------UPDATE--------------------
I now use the Platform.runLater(); BUT I get "System cannot find file specified error"

The code that produces the error is that:

```
BufferedReader readr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

And here is all the code needed:

```
try{
            data.updateConsole("Starting server!");
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start javaw -Xmx2048M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true --nojline");
            data.setOutputStream(proc.getOutputStream());
            is = proc.getErrorStream();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader readr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Do I need -In the process- to include the full path of the file , or just the name of it? Both jars are in the same directory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message means that you need to run a UI update in a FX thread. To do this, you just wrap your update into a `Runnable` and schedule it for execution:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        data.cons.setText(newText);
    }
});
```